# Pass "this" into nested data function Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, element-ui

In VueJS component with [Element UI](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/datetime-picker#picker-options), I'm using disabledDate which is "a function determining if a date is disabled with that date as its parameter".

In this case, I can disable Saturday and Sunday with this code.

```
  pickerOptions: {
    disabledDate (date) {
      if (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6) {
        return true
      }
      return false
    }
  }
```

I wanted to pass `this` into `disabledDate` function so I can disable other dates (with epoch) as well.

Here is what I intend to do.

```
  pickerOptions: {
    firstDayOfWeek: 1,
    disabledDate (date) {
      if (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6) {
        if (this.endDate > this.startDate) {
          return true
        }
      }
      return false
    }
  }
```

The problem I'm running into is `this` is `undefined` when it's passed into `pickerOptions`'s `disabledDate` function. Is there anyway to access to `this` inside that nested function?

Note: `pickerOptions` is inside of `data` in a Vue component.

Comment: No. But even if I try `this.$props` it won't work because `this` is `undefined` in this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` never gets passed to `pickerOptions`'s function, you're just trying to access it. You get `undefined` every time because it's another context when you call the function. This is how you would pass it (**Warning**: don't use this code in your project, this is just for a demonstration):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    test: 'test',
    pickerOptions: {
      firstDayOfWeek: 1,
      disabledDate: (date, context) => {
        if (date === null) {
          console.log(context.test);
          return true;
        }
        return false
      },
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.pickerOptions.disabledDate(null, this); // alternatevely use call(), .apply() or .bind()
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
```

What you should do is to move `disabledDate` function from the `data` property of your component (it's called "data" for a reason) to the `methods` or `computed` (depends on how you are going to use this function). In this case `this` will refer to the component instance.

EDIT: I took a look at how the component you use works. Seems like the best option would be to write `pickerOptions` as a `computed` property that returns an object with parameters for the component. Then you can pass this object to `picker-options` property.

Answer (score 0):

From what @oniondomes suggested, I've converted `pickerOptions` into computed property and used it like this.

**Final Solution**

```
computed: {
  pickerOptions () {
      let startDate = this.start_date
      let options = {}
      options.firstDayOfWeek = 1
      options.disabledDate = function (date) {
        // needs to subtract 1 to enable current day to select
        if (date < startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - 1)) {
          return true
        }
        return false
      }
      return options
   }
}
```